# Does $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ contain $|x|=1$ with $x$ not a power of $\zeta_n$?

Tags: ring-theory, roots-of-unity, cyclotomic-fields

Let $\zeta_n=e^\frac{{2i\pi}}{n}$. Suppose $n$ is even. Then $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ contains no roots of unity that are not powers of $\zeta_n$ because this is true of $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_n]$ which is a way to show that these fields are non-isomorphic for different values of even $n$. If $n$ is odd, then $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]=\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{2n}]$. I was wondering if this extends to all $x$ with $|x|=1$. I know this is false for the fields. However, are there are any $x$ with $|x|=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ that are not $n$th roots of unity? Clearly there are none for $n=2,4,6$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez the OP is asking if the question in the subject line (also asked at the end of the post) is true.  What is "false for fields" is exactly that question, e.g., $3/5 + (4/5)i$ has absolute value $1$ in $\mathbf Q(\zeta_4)$ and is not a root of unity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $K$ be an *abelian* Galois extension of $\mathbf Q$, such as a cyclotomic field. View it as a subfield of $\mathbf C$. Since $K/\mathbf Q$ is Galois and complex conjugation fixes $\mathbf Q$, complex conjugation is a field automorphism of $K$.  It would be the identity automorphism if $K \subset \mathbf R$, but also your question trivially has the answer "no" for $K$ if it is a subfield of $\mathbf R$, so you could assume complex conjugation is not the identity on $K$ below.  But I actually won't need to know whether or not complex conjugation is the identity on $K$ below.

Theorem. *With notation as above, if $\alpha \in K$ has absolute value $1$ then every $\mathbf Q$-conjugate of $\alpha$ has absolute value $1$.*

*Proof*. We assume $\alpha\overline{\alpha} = 1$. Let $\alpha' \in K$ be a $\mathbf Q$-conjugate of $\alpha$, so $\alpha' = \sigma(\alpha)$ for some $\sigma \in {\rm Gal}(K/\mathbf Q)$.  Then $\overline{\alpha'} = \overline{\sigma(\alpha)} = \sigma(\overline{\alpha})$ since elements of ${\rm Gal}(K/\mathbf Q)$ commute. Then
$$
|\alpha'|^2 = \alpha'\overline{\alpha'} = \sigma(\alpha)\sigma(\overline{\alpha}) = \sigma(\alpha\overline{\alpha}) = \sigma(1) = 1,
$$
so $|\alpha'| = 1$.  $\Box$

**Note**.  The idea for the above argument comes from the answer by Cam McLeman [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38680/can-an-algebraic-number-on-the-unit-circle-have-a-conjugate-with-absolute-value).

Corollary.  *With notation as above, an algebraic integer in $K$ with absolute value $1$ must be a root of unity*.

*Proof*.  If an algebraic integer in $K$ has absolute value $1$, then by the theorem all of its $\mathbf Q$-conjugates have absolute value $1$.  A famous theorem of Kronecker says that an algebraic integer whose $\mathbf Q$-conjugates all have absolute value $1$ must be a root of unity.  $\Box$